# Conditional Formatting using And in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column of data...A1, A2, .. A30

Each cell contains a number. If A1, A2, and A3 are less than 0.5, I want B1 to change color to Red. If either one of them is above 0.5, then no color.

Then I want A2, A3, A4.  Then A3, A4, A5. so forth until I hit the last cell.

I tried doing something like A1:A3, but what happen, it acts like a Or statement, rather than And statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try conditional formatting using the formula in the cell B1:

```
=AND(AND(A1<0.5;A2<0.5);A3<0.5)
```

or simpler

```
=(A1<0.5)*(A2<0.5)*(A3<0.5)
```

and setting a proper color if the condition is true.